# HTML searching issue

Tags: html, database, search

So, HTML newbie here and am having an issue where I have a website that just hosts files. I have a working search function on the site in two places. One on the homepage where the search works perfectly fine. Once a search is inputed (searching 'pop' for instance), the url states:

http://website.com/?op=catalogue&k=pop&ftype=

But, on the second page, when I input a search term, it seems to add to the url and doesnt go anywhere. For example:

http://website.com/e2aqev6btnnv/head.jpg?op=catalogue&k=pop&ftype=

Instead of erasing the head.jpg file in the URL and accepting the new search term, it just adds it and the page doesn't go anywhere. Please help

Here is the code I have for the search:

```
<br>
<Form method="GET" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="catalogue">
<input type="search" onfocus="fieldReceivedFocus()" name="k" id="search" value="">
```

Comment: We need to see some code if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Form method="GET" action="http://website.com">
```

what will tell it what page to send the form data to, in your case it is the main page, otherwise it sends it to the current page.

You MAY need to change

```
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="catalogue">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="search">
```

I don't know how the backend of your site is coded but based on what I see in the urls i think you will need to.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately it did not help. I wonder if there is a way to clear the current URL and use http://www.website.com/(the new search) instead of just adding to the current page's URL